# Есть программа на java, нужно создать графическую оболочку

Tags: java

Нужно создать программу, чтобы человек вводил названия фруктов и их количество, а потом выводилась сумма, используя графический интерфейс, то есть ввод и вывод не через консоль а в отдельном окошечке, с отдельным полем для ввода и выводом (и при возможности кнопкой "посчитать"). Есть код программы, но не могу разобраться, как добавить графический интерфейс.
Код программы, к которой нужно добавить графический интерфейс:

```
package com.somepackage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern =
                Pattern.compile("^([А-Яа-я]+) - (\\d+)$");
        Map<String, Integer> fruits = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            String x = reader.readLine();
            if (x.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println(
                        String.join(", ", fruits.keySet()) + " - " +
                                fruits.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
                break;
            }
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String fruit = matcher.group(1);
                Integer count =
                        Integer.parseInt(
                                matcher.group(2));
                fruits.put(fruit, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее вам нужно написать полностью и заново графический интерфейс, к которому вы добавите две маленькие функции. Одна с `fruits.put(fruit, count)` и вторая с расчетом `String.join(", ", fruits.keySet()) + " - " + fruits.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784).

Если не позволяет религия, можно конечно посмотреть в сторону Java Swing - но это уже уходящая технология. Не советую тратить время на его изучение.

Краткий [туториал по JavaFX здесь](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/index.html)

По сути вам надо нарисовать окошко (в терминах JavaFX `Scene`) с несколькими текстовыми виджетами (в терминах JavaFX `TextField`), куда будут вводиться названия фруктов и окошко вывода (в терминах JavaFX `TextArea`), куда будет выводиться результат парсинга.

Окошко можно нарисовать с помощью [JavaFX Scene Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/get-started-tutorial/overview.htm#JSBGS164) весь расчет "посадить" на событие нажатия кнопки (в терминах JavaFX `Button`)